# What is the purpose of modulo 4 in the masking key in the protocol of Websocket?

Tags: websocket

In [section 5.3 of rfc 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3), the spec states:

> Octet i of the transformed data ("transformed-octet-i") is the XOR of
> octet i of the original data ("original-octet-i") with octet at index
> i modulo 4 of the masking key ("masking-key-octet-j"):
>
> ```
>  j                   = i MOD 4
>  transformed-octet-i = original-octet-i XOR masking-key-octet-j
> ```

But why? What does modulo 4 do for this algorithm?

Comment: The masking key is 4 bytes long.  *Something* is needed to reduce the arbitrary index of the original data to a 0..3 index that can be used with the masking key, and the modulo operation is the simplest/standard way of doing so.

Comment: @jsonharper thank you for your answer but I still don't understand. Octet i is 8 bits long because it is an octet. If octet i was 10010010 = 146, then i mod 4 = 146 mod 4 = 2. I just don't understand how this accomplished what you described: Something is needed to reduce the arbitrary index of the original data to a 0..3 index that can be used with the masking key

Comment: The modulo isn't being applied to the actual data, it's only for the indexes.  For example, if there are ten bytes of data, which would have indexes 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, the key indexes that are XORed with each one of those bytes are 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1.